# Mongoid not detecting change to localized field when setting field with xxxx_translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

**Gem Versions**
I am using Rails 3.2.18 and Mongoid 3.1.6.

**The problem**
I need to set a value for any locale in a localized field, not just the one that is currently in I18n.locale. I am setting it using title_translations['en'] = 'some title', but when doing this, mongoid does not detect the change (not dirty) and so nothing is saved.

**The Model**
I have a mongoid model with a localized field like the following:

```
class ApiMethod
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title, type: String, localize: true

  attr_accessible :title, :title_translations

end
```

**Console Example**
Below is an example of setting the title two ways, one as title = 'xxx' and one as title_translations['en'] = 'xxx' and the result of testing if the object has changed.

```
2.1.2 :083 > a = ApiMethod.first
 => #<ApiMethod _id: 5541cb17fb6fc67028000006, title: {"en"=>"Dataset Catalog"}> 
2.1.2 :084 > a.title
 => "Dataset Catalog" 
2.1.2 :085 > a.title_translations
 => {"en"=>"Dataset Catalog"} 
2.1.2 :086 > a.title = 'new title'
 => "new title" 
2.1.2 :087 > a.changed?
 => true    ## YEA! - THIS IS CORRECT
2.1.2 :088 > a.changed
 => ["title"] 
2.1.2 :089 > a.reload
 => #<ApiMethod _id: 5541cb17fb6fc67028000006, title: {"en"=>"Dataset Catalog"}> 
2.1.2 :090 > a.title_translations['en'] = 'this is a new title'
 => "this is a new title" 
2.1.2 :091 > a.title
 => "this is a new title" 
2.1.2 :092 > a.title_translations
 => {"en"=>"this is a new title"} 
2.1.2 :093 > a.changed?
 => false     ## BOO! - THIS IS NOT CORRECT
```

**Please Help!**
Am I doing something wrong or missing something? Is it not possible to set a localized field value for a locale that is not the current I18n.locale value?

Thank you for your help!

**Update**
I just tried something else and this works. Instead of setting the title_translations for a specific locale, I tried setting the entire title_translations object:

```
2.1.2 :114 > a = ApiMethod.only(:title).first
 => #<ApiMethod _id: 5541cb17fb6fc67028000006, title: {"en"=>"Dataset Catalog"}> 
2.1.2 :115 > x = a.title_translations.dup
 => {"en"=>"Dataset Catalog"} 
2.1.2 :116 > x['en'] = 'this is a new title'
 => "this is a new title" 
2.1.2 :117 > x
 => {"en"=>"this is a new title"} 
2.1.2 :118 > a.title_translations = x
 => {"en"=>"this is a new title"} 
2.1.2 :119 > a.title_translations
 => {"en"=>"this is a new title"} 
2.1.2 :120 > a.changed?
 => true 
2.1.2 :121 > a.title_change
 => [{"en"=>"Dataset Catalog"}, {"en"=>"this is a new title"}]
```

So it seems like if I replace the entire value for title_translations and not just a specific locale, the change is detected. While it is nice that this works, it is not ideal. Thoughts?